# Second derivative of lognormal function in R?

Tags: r, integral, derivative

I need to find the second derivate of the lognormal distribution using R. I need it because I will be squaring that second derivative and integrating from 0 to infinity. But to do that I need code that will produce the function for me to evaluate in the integral.

My final equation looks like this:

R(f'') = integrate (from 0 to inf) (f''(x))^2 dx

Where f is the lognormal distribution, and
f''(x) refers to the second derivative of the function.

Comment: I am not quite sure, if that's really something to use R for, since it's more a numerical programming language.

Comment: When you speak of the "log normal distribution" are you intending us to consider this the density or the integrated probability function?

Comment: I think it would be best to use the Newton Raphon algorithm, R has implemented the functions `nlm(.)` Or `optim(.)`, For the minimization of functions.